# Copy input type="date" value to another input type="date" jquery

Tags: jquery, date, input

Good day! I am creating a web based application where in, one of its function is to copy the selected date in the input type="date" form to another input type="date" input. How can I do this? I am trying to do this as I can, but still, I can't make it. Please response if someone knows it, thank you very much!

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a id selector you can achieve.

```
<input type="date" id="date1" value="" />

<input type="date" id="date2" value="" />
```

Jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#date1').blur( function(){
     $('#date2').val($(this).val());
});
});
```

Provided you can add unique id selectors in the html.